# How to align this div in the center so that it is responsive on all devices

Tags: html, css, alignment, centering

I'm making a portfolio website and want to have this little logo in the middle of the page, but it is not responsive.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.box1 {
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0 auto;
  i think i'm messing up here
 width: 90px;
  height: 100px;
  background: rgb(31, 31, 31);
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
}

.box1 a {
  position: relative;
  font-family: 'Roboto Slab', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 22px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  top: 50%;
}

.box1 a:hover {
  color: rgb(241, 241, 241);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <nav>
    <div class="box1"><a href="#">Top</a></div>
  </nav>
</div>
```

### Expectations

I Expect the text to be bottom aligned with the box and have some space in the bottom and the whole div in the center of the page, this will also function as a home button. also suggestions/feedback would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Just add

```
 top:50%;
   left:50%;
   transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
```

to your `position:absolute` to center anything. Remember absolute only works to a position defined parent.

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;

  }
html, body { 
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

    .box1 { 
       position: absolute;
       margin: 0 auto;
       top:50%;
       left:50%;
       transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
       
       width: 90px;
       height: 100px;
       background: rgb(31, 31, 31);
       float: left; 
       text-align: center;
  }

  .box1 a { 
      position: relative;
      font-family: 'Roboto Slab',sans-serif;
      font-weight: 700;
      font-size: 22px;
      text-decoration: none;
      color: #fff;
      top: 50%;            
  }

  .box1 a:hover { 
      color: rgb(241, 241, 241);   
  }
```

```html
<div class="container">
     <nav> 
         <div class="box1"><a href="#">Top</a></div>
     </nav>
</div>
```